# sitemaping in google search console not working because backend is hosted in another url

Tags: reactjs, express, sitemap, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

i have this site where i create new url based on new questions asked
i am trying to index the new url created to sitemap.txt and add it to googles search console

i am generating new urls and new sites urls are being written in backend in to a file called sitemap.txt but i dont know how to connect it to  googles search console

i have my front end in firebase made with react js and backend is experess.js and is hosted in heroku
my site url is  https://wixten.com and i have added this url to googles serch console

the periodicaly  generated  sitemap.txt is in express.js as in img

in the seccond img u can see that i have added  https://askover.herokuapp.com/sitemap.txt
in https://wixten.com googleserch console
what am i doing wrong here and how can i set such that new urls added will be re cralled by googles serch bots to index in google

[image: sitemap in express.js]

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: This is now asked at webmasters [Google Search Console rejects sitemap as "invalid path" when it is hosted on a backend server from another domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138008/google-search-console-rejects-sitemap-as-invalid-path-when-it-is-hosted-on-a-b) and should be deleted here.